# Specifying a per-repository hgrc file

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I'm setting up a centrally hosted Mercurial repository.  I would like to be able to define only a small set of users that are able to access that repository (maybe 3 or 4) - what do I need to write in the .hg/hgrc file that in order to make it work like this?

thanks, P

Comment: How will these people be accessing the repository?

Comment: Generally using something like Tortoise HG...

Comment: The "how" should be one of the options on this list: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories

TortoiseHG is just a (great!) client.

Comment: ah ha, thanks. I think it's the "How" I hadn't come across, will delve deeper!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't provide a user authentication system -- that has to come from something else.  However, it **does** provide an authorization system that uses the "who" answer from the external authentication system to decide what that "who" can do.

Popular *external* authentication systems include:

- HTTP authentication as provided by your web server (Apache, etc.)
- SSH authentication as provided by sshd
- file system level user authentication as provided by your operating system
- **Note:** `hg serve` **does not** have an authentication system, so it's not usable w/ per-user access controls

Accessing mercurial (either its web interface or its command line interface) through one of those systems, properly configured, provided mercurial with the answer to "who?".

Once Mercurial learns *who* is making the request then the `allow_push` and `allow_read` settings in the repository's `.hg/hgrc` file will determine what that *who* can do.

So the *how* of setting this up depends on what means of access you're using, which is what Callahad was asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sharing the repository through the Mercurial web interface, then read the [**Web interface configuration**](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web) section of the [**hgrc**](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) man page.